# remove variable after loading page

Tags: php, xml, session

How can I stop my xml loading every time my index.php (template page) loads except the first time?

I am using my index.php page as a template that refreshes and shows different data depending on `$_GET[''];` values and some xml data. I want to load the xml into a varaiable the first time the page loads but not every time. Below is my code.

```
session_start();
$load_xml = true;

    if($load_xml){
        $xml = simplexml_load_file('PosterData.xml');
        $load_xml = false;
            $_SESSION['xmlData'] = $xml;
    }
```

Probably with the above code is $load_xml will never be false. Any ideas how I can accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
session_start();

if(empty($_SESSION['xmlData'])){
    $xml = simplexml_load_file('PosterData.xml');
    $_SESSION['xmlData'] = $xml;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. It was right in front of me. Not sure how i missed this. +1 and I will check this as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

You could set a `$_SESSION` variable - like you already have - `not_first_load` that would do exactly what it looks like it will do.

Then:

```
session_start();

if(!isset($_SESSION['not_first_load'])
  $xml = simplexml_load_file('PosterData.xml');
  $_SESSION['xmlData'] = $xml;
  $_SESSION['not_first_load'] = 1;
}
```

Comment: That's rather unnecessary, to set one variable just to track whether or not the other has been set. There are `empty()` and `isset()` designed to do exactly that task.